# how to query all objects in one set that do not have a foreign key in another object in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following objects:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)

class Member(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

I can get all the members assigned to a group with this:

```
group_members = group.groupmember_set.all()
```

All of the members available for a certain customer with this:

```
member_list = customer.members.all()
```

I want to create a list of all of members available for a customer that are not assigned to a group.  Something like:

```
not_group_members = Member.objects.filter(?)
```

How can I create this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with:

```
customer.members.filter(groupmember__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup, that's not possible since Member has a non-nullable foreign key to group.

However, if you change to this:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True)
```

Then you can find Members that are not in any group.

```
not_group_members = Member.objects.filter(group=None)
```

Comment: "Member has a non-nullable foreign key to group." I think you're confusing `Customer` and `Group`.

Answer (score 0):

```
customer.members.filter(groupmember_set__isnull=True)
```

(I used `members` here because you did, even though the default related name would be `member_set`.)